# OSX – remove google update drives

Tags: macos, google-drive

In finder I have dozens of Google update drives but it's not possible to eject them. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this one...uninstall google drive

- Click the Google Drive icon, which you’ll find in your computer's menubar at the top of the screen.
- From the drop-down menu, select Preferences.
- When the Google Drive Preferences window opens, choose Disconnect account.
- After you've confirmed disconnecting your account, open the Applications folder and move the Google Drive icon to your trash.

  After you've uninstalled Google Drive for your Mac, the Google Drive folder – including the files and folders it contains – will remain on your computer. At this point, you can delete your Google Drive folder and its contents without deleting anything in your Google Drive on the web.

Comment: The problem will return the moment he re-installs Google Drive